# How to always have a header on top of each page when printing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

In my website, I have a really tall table spanning multiple pages when printing. Is there a way I can have the header row, show on top of each page when printing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most browsers do this automatically.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Your header row repeats on every page.</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Your body rows will fill the pages.</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: but if the header row is fixed, it will overlap with rows on each page?

Comment: @omega the browser simply drops the header row at the top of each page. It doesn't overlap any of the body rows. No CSS is required.

Comment: I tried it, it does overlap with the body cells, also the heights of the cells are all different.

Comment: Specify @media print { thead { position: relative } }

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for that you can use the media print and just include this in every page :)

http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/CSS_for_print_tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Give your head row

`position :fixed`

Now it will be repeated on every page.

Source - https://makandracards.com/makandra/4845-repeat-an-element-on-every-printed-page-with-css

Comment: but if the header row is fixed, it will overlap with rows on each page?

Comment: @omega you can give top padding to normal cells, to not let them overlap.

Comment: the problem with that is the cells are not all the same height, it is all different.